# Getting the next turn/direction in Mapbox

Tags: maps, mapbox, directions, mapbox-android

I'm trying to get the direction of the upcoming turn while travelling, i.e. I want to trigger an event in my app according to the direction of the upcoming turn.

I've tried using event listeners, taking help of the documentation and the provided examples but as I'm pretty new to android studio and mapbox, I've not been successful (my app either crashed or the function would never get triggered). I've also tried searching for getting the voice commands into text form or log form but have failed.

While my current code does display directions and gives voiced instructions, I can't figure out how to access either of them. I'd like to know if there's a simple way of achieving what I'm after without using any event listeners.

```java
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;

    private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
    private MapboxNavigation navigation;
    private Button button;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mapboxMap.setStyle(getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                  enableLocationComponent(style);

                  addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(style);

                  mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);

                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean simulateRoute = true;
                        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                                .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                                .build();

                        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        loadedMapStyle.addImage("destination-icon-id",
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));
        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("destination-source-id");
        Log.d(TAG, "addDestinationIconSymbolLayer: " + geoJsonSource);
        loadedMapStyle.addSource(geoJsonSource);
        SymbolLayer destinationSymbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("destination-symbol-layer-id", "destination-source-id");
        destinationSymbolLayer.withProperties(
                iconImage("destination-icon-id"),
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconIgnorePlacement(true)
        );
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(destinationSymbolLayer);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    @Override
    public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {

        Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
        Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude(),
                locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());


        GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");
        Log.d(TAG, "Does this even work");
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick: " + source.toString());
        if (source != null) {
            source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
        }

        getRoute(originPoint, destinationPoint);
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);

        return true;
    }

    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {

        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                        if (response.body() == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                            return;
                        } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);



                        if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                            navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                        } else {
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                        }
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });

    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {


        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this, loadedMapStyle);
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap.getStyle());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
    // Add the mapView's own lifecycle methods to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to look at using an event listener for a custom milestone. Here's a link to the docs:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/milestones/#milestone-event-listener

Comment: Yeah...I tried using the docs to write my code. However, using the code given their either gave me an error or the onMilestoneEvent function would never get triggered. I even tried using the examples as a reference, but I couldn't get them to work either. I'd appreciate if someone could send me a link for a simple example using onMilestoneEvent that a beginner could understand.